# Print one time in while in and out position

Tags: lua, fivem

this code print me test while I'm in the position, how i can print it one time until im out and in again?

```
while true do
    Citizen.Wait(1000)
    for k,v in pairs(zone) do
        if GetDistanceBetweenCoords(v.xyz, GetEntityCoords(GetPlayerPed(-1))) < 100 then
                print('test')
                break
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to detect when your condition of the player being in range is true, and print `test` *only once* while the player remains in range.

To do this, I would use a boolean called `playerInRange` that is set to true the first time the distance check passes. Then you can check whether that boolean is true every subsequent time. When the check does not pass (the player is no longer in range), set it back to false.

To demonstrate what I mean, for convenience of checking the outcome of the loop, I've moved the distance check into its own function.

```
function CheckDistanceFromZone(zone, distance)
    for k,v in pairs(zone) do
        if GetDistanceBetweenCoords(v.xyz, GetEntityCoords(GetPlayerPed(-1))) < distance then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

--

local playerInRange = false

while true do
    Citizen.Wait(1000)
    if CheckDistanceFromZone(zone, 100) then
        if not playerInRange then
            playerInRange = true
            print("test")
        end
    else
        playerInRange = false
    end
end
```